# mongoengine Custom Field Names

Tags: mongodb, field, mongoengine

I have defined a document type in monoengine as follows:

```
from mongoengine import *

import datetime

class User(Document):
    username = StringField(min_length = 1, max_length = 20, regex = '(\w+)', required = True, unique = True)
    password = StringField(min_length = 5, required = True)
    email = EmailField(required = True, unique = True)
    name = StringField(min_length = 3, max_length = 40, required = True)
    date_created = DateTimeField(default = datetime.datetime.utcnow, required = True)
```

However, when there is an error, the field name is the member variable. For some fields, this will look quite ugly for the user. For example, "date_created" should really say "Date Created".

So, I am trying to find a way to tell Mongoengine to use a "nicer" name instead of the member variable name but I can't seem to find a way. I've tried name and verbose_name but they don't appear to do anything and I've looked though the docs, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`verbose_name` is used for outputting to a frontend user and its up to you to output the verbose_name instead of the field name when rendering - eg in a form.

Comment: So, I can't just print out the contents of the exception where it uses verbose_name instead?

Comment: Exception tracebacks are generally for developer consumption not end users and as such the Model Object attribute name is more explicit. 

Can you clarify what you are trying to achieve / how you are using the exceptions?

Comment: Currently, I am writing out str(exception) to the user as it seems to work well. However, if I cannot change the text that is in the exception that MongoEngine produces, then I can format it myself.

Comment: Ok Currently not possible add a feature request on github and I'll evaluate.  If you can add a test demonstrating what you currently do / expect to happen that would be helpful!